# What Methods are Used for Satellite to Site Visibility Calculation?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, mathematics

In the paper, [*Rapid Satellite-to-Site Visibility Determination Based on Self-Adaptive Interpolation Technique*](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1611/1611.02402.pdf) it is claimed that "Satellite-to-site visibility periods are typically determined by the conventional brute force method."

Is this statement really true? Are there popular alternative ways? How does AGI STK handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common method, by far, is brute force, by propagating the relevant satellite and then calculating the visibility. There are however many ways to optimize this brute force:

- Large delta-t until "close" and then smaller delta-t after that
- Using Multi-threading to reduce processing time

Few github examples:

- https://github.com/shupp/Predict
- https://github.com/jeyoder/ThingsInSpace